# This Decision Split activity is not configured. Configure all activities before activating

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have started building my Journey as slowly and tactful as possible. The entry point is a data extension containing a field called `FirstDepartueDateTime`. A Decision Split activity checks whether this date is after 2 days from now. I then add a Send Email activity after that and that is it for now. The Journey looks ok and the Decision Split is orange on the canvas.

[image]

I save the Journey and click on the validate button. But I get the following error message:

> This Decision Split activity is not configured. Configure all
>   activities before activating.

And my canvas turns into this:
[image]

As I click on the now red Decision Split, I notice that `FirstDepartureDateTime` attribute is replaced with `Invalid Attribute` and it seems as if the attribute together with the condition go missing.
[image]

The attribute `FirstDepartueDateTime` exists in the Entry Point Data Extension and nothing has changed. I cannot validate this journey and I don't know what is missing? Is this because the Entry Point Data extension is empty?

Comment: Did you try deleting the Entry data extension from the Journey and selecting it back again?

Comment: @RachidMamai This is what I just did to no avail.

Comment: @RachidMamai The entry point data extension is currently empty. I don't think this should cause a problem, right?

Comment: No, that's not the cause. It's a dumb question but is FirstDepartueDateTime a date field?

Comment: @RachidMamai yes, it's a date field and that is how I can add those conditions (e.g. is after two days from now). Please look at the question as I added a third picture of how the Decision Split activity looks after the failed validation.

Comment: Sometimes Journey Builder shows this error randomly. In most cases, I had to delete and select back the entry source, save and then refresh the page. That solved the problem for me..

Comment: I had a similar issue, where it wouldn’t take the ”equals” operator and instead I had to use “begins with”. Upon creating a new version, this somehow fixed itself.

Comment: @RachidMamai I removed the EntryPoint, saved, added it back and then saved again and this seemed to make it work. Otherwise, it was very confusing. Thank you for the suggestion. Do you think we should post it as an answer? This looks more like a bug.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, maybe it will help someone avoid this confusion in the futur.. But I agree, this seems to be a backend problem on JourneyBuilder and it's very annoying..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've suggested in the comments, sometimes Journey Builder shows this error randomly. In most cases, I had to remove and select back the entry source, save and then refresh the page. That solved the problem for me in most cases.